# Get value from mysql table in same cell as another value PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a working register and log in system for members on my website that logs details into a MySql database. My MySql table for members has a row named 'id' that distinguishes one account from another (where every id is different). I have a way to get the user id from the table when they are logged in using sessions but I need to know how to get another value from the same cell (for example, the email address they used to register).

Here is a demonstration of my table:

---

**id | username | email**

48 | JohnSmith | johnsmith@example.com

49 | PeterGriffin | petergriffin@example.com

---

If the account with the id number 48 is logged in, how can I get the value from the same account in the 'email' row (returning 'johnsmith@example.com')?

Comment: with a select querry

Comment: it would seriously take less time to find the answer, than write this question, people are weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `select` statement would do that:

```
SELECT email FROM members WHERE id = 48
```

now you can go read some [php/mysql tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=php%20mysql&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=php%20mysql%20tutorials) on how to get the two working together.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the id is a primary key (if not, then make sure it is), you can request any attribute from the same record using a simple SELECT query.  For example to retrieve the email:

```
SELECT email from [TABLE] where id=[your session id]
```

Comment: would make no difference if it was NOT the primary key, or a key at all

Comment: I agree, but in this case the id should really be the PK